# Copying down results from an ARRAY

Tags: sql, arrays, google-bigquery, unnest

I'm having issues with joining together separate tables what don't have anything in common. Essentially, I have a table with all possible customer IDs and a separate table for all possible dateweek ranges. I want to join them together in order to use at a later time to find date ranges for customer IDs where they are null in another dataset.

SELECT
customer_id,
ARRAY(
SELECT
DISTINCT CONCAT(year,week) AS yearweek
FROM
sales)
FROM
customers

While this works, I need to get the customer IDs to copy down in order to use it as a JOIN later on.

| customer_id | yearweek |
| --- | --- |
| 4517507 | 202201 |
|  | 202202 |
|  | 202203 |
|  | 202204 |
|  | 202205 |
| 4517512 | 202201 |
|  | 202202 |
|  | 202203 |
|  | 202204 |
|  | 202205 |

In the end, I want it to look like this:

| customer_id | yearweek |
| --- | --- |
| 4517507 | 202201 |
| 4517507 | 202202 |
| 4517507 | 202203 |
| 4517507 | 202204 |
| 4517507 | 202205 |
| 4517512 | 202201 |
| 4517512 | 202202 |
| 4517512 | 202203 |
| 4517512 | 202204 |
| 4517512 | 202205 |

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT customer_id, yearweek 
FROM customers, (SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT(year,week) AS yearweek FROM sales)
```